# Why am I getting System.char[] printed out in this case?

Tags: c#, string, return-value

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here, but I can't seem to. I have this method that takes in a string and reverses it. However, when I print out the reversed string from the caller method, I just get "System.Char []" instead of the actual reversed string.

```
    static string reverseString(string toReverse)
    {
        char[] reversedString = toReverse.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(reversedString);
        return reversedString.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Calling `ToString` on a `T` array in .NET will always return `"T[]"`. You want to use this instead: `new string(reversedString)`.

Answer (score 7):

By calling `ToString` you just get the default implementation that every class inherits from `object`. .NET can't provide a special implementation just for an array of char; the override would have to apply to all types of array.

Instead, you can pass the array to String's constructor, `return new String(reversedString)`.