# Why am I getting System.Char[] output? How do I get the string?

Tags: c#, arrays, encryption, char

I'm trying to make a Caesar cipher program and I'm working on the Write method but it will only print out System.Char[]. What can I do to print out the reformatted string? Am I even converting everything right?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Caesar_Cipher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Read or Write?");
            string input1 = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            if (input1 == "read")
            {
            }
            if (input1 == "write")
            {
                write();
            }

        }
        static void read()
        {

        }
        public static void write()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write something to translate,");
            string value = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("How many shifts do you want?");
            int shift = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            char[] Read = value.ToCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < Read.Length; i++)
            {
                int b = i - (Read.Length + shift);
                int c = Read.Length - shift;
                if (b <= 0)
                {
                    Read[c] = Read[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    int shift1 = i + shift;
                    Read[shift1] = Read[i];
                }
            }
             string d = Read.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(d);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because an Array of Char doesn't know how to transform itself in a string. So the base class Object kicks in and returns the name of the type. Use _string d = new string(Read);_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting System.char\[\] printed out in this case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562078/why-am-i-getting-system-char-printed-out-in-this-case)

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is convert an array of `char`s to `string`:

```
char[] chars = ...;
...

string s = new string(chars);
```